# how to draw line around a UITableView

Tags: ios, uikit, cgcontext

I know how to draw lines/rect in a single view. But I'm lost in this case:
I have a `UIView` A and a `UITableView` B. A is added to a viewController's view, and B is added to A. As You know, `UITableView` had no border and hence I try to draw line along the bounds of the B.
Below is the code how I organize these views:

```
if (_tableView) {
        [_tableView release];
        _tableView = nil;
    }


    UITableView * temp = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    temp.delegate = self;
    temp.dataSource = self;
    temp.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    temp.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;

    self.table = temp;
    [temp release];
    temp = nil;
    [self.table setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 2, 0, 2)];

    [_transparencyView addSubview:self.table];


    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:_transparencyView];
    [_transparencyView setNeedsDisplayInRect:tableRect];
```

The `_transparencyView` is an instance of `ZJTransparencyView` inherited from `UIView`, and its implement  file is like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"%s:%@",__func__,NSStringFromCGRect(rect));

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);



}
```

The problem I met is :
When I add the tableview and call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`, the rect send to  `drawRect:` is always {0,0,320,460}. It seems that tableRect has no effect. I don't know why it happens.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tableRect is what you initialize the table, you should have control over it. If you think that the correct rectangle is not refreshed, call `setNeedsDisplay` without specifying rectangle. But, there really is no need to do custom drawing for this since `UITableView` inherits from `UIView` and you can draw a border around `UIView`.

Import QuartzCore

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and set the border for the UITableView as,

```
temp.layer.borderColor=[UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;
temp.layer.borderWidth=2;
```

Comment: This is what I need. Acturally I also want to use the <code>layer</code>, but I didn't find the method. Thanks.